# I don't understand this c++ array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

In C++, when an array is declared like that

```
int myArray[8] = {0,};
```

what does it mean?

Comment: Are you asking about the comma or why there's just one `0`?

Comment: I'm asking about the comma, but I suppose that omit it is not a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int myArray[8] = {0,};`

It's the same as
`int myArray[8] = {0};`
will populate the whole array with 0;

This is allowed in case that someone would want to add more elements to that array.
For example :

```
int myArray[] = {

        1,
        2,
        3,
};
```

Can easily be populated later.

Comment: "can easily be populated later"... ?? Also, what does the example with length-inferrence from the initializers have to do with anything?

Comment: You can't "add more elements" to an array. It has a fixed number of elements.

Answer (score 7):

This effectively initializes all elements of an array to 0. You give the first element explicitly (0), and all that you omit are <strike>default-initialized</strike> value-initialized, which is also 0 for your type. The comma after the 0 is optional.

Comment: All the remaining elements are in fact value-initialized. If they were default-initialized, all hell would break loose.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not a language lawyer, but - for example - accepted answer for the linked question states that default initialization is used in this case - both for C and C++.

Comment: I can't see the linked question, but it sounds like the answer is wrong, at least in C++. Default initialization of ints means no initialization (I know, it sounds silly but that is the way it is.) EDIT: I see it has just been "fixed".

Comment: Here is a proof that default initialization is used: http://ideone.com/VBXyMR You can try yourself with ints - you can give only first value (for example 42), and the rest will be initialized with 0. ints have "default value" - it's just that initializing PODs on stack doesn't call their "default constructor". In C++11 you can even use this default value: `int a {};` will initialize this variable to default value of int, which is 0.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: The standard defines `default-initialization`, `zero-initialization`, `value-initialization` and `aggregate-initialization`. You don't get to make up their definitions. `8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]`: §6 zero-initialization, §7 default-initialization, §8 value-initialize and `8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]` for aggregates.

Comment: That is proof of *value initialization*. It is a matter of terminology. Default initialization of an int does not initialize it.

Comment: @Deduplicator - ok, here's the final (?) draft for C++11 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf on page 204 in item 7 doesn't mention "value-initialization" - `int()` given as example is an example of default initialization. Item 11 is similar an mentions default initialization of whole row with expression `float()`.

Comment: `float()` is a *value initialization*. If you find a quote that says it is a default initialization, you should include it in your answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza - personally I would say that having "int a;" on stack is not "default initialized", but "uninitialized".

Comment: My cites stay *substantially* the same (just re-numbered slightly). And neither of those paragraphs of `[dcl.init.aggr]` you name mention default-initialization. Just because you don't like the standard terminology does not give you licence to ignore it, especially as there is good reason for it.

Comment: @FreddieChopin I don't really care what you say personally. I care about what the standard says. That terminology allows me to communicate efficiently with other people who understand it without being subject to personal preferences.

Comment: OK, you are right - "value" is T(), I mistakenly considered that to be "default". My confusion comes from the fact, that for a class type "default" is the same as "value" (;